# take the activity content to dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to make a custom dialog in which I want to make call by yes Button and cancel the dialog by no button. But on the text view in dialog I want confirmation dialog saying "Call : number". I have taken this no from the user in main Activity and I am unable to bring this No to Dialog. How can I do this?
I have tried by intent and Shared preferences but all in vain. Give me Suggestions.

I have written following code in Main activity class.

```
package com.example.deepak.phone_call;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button b;
    EditText edittext1;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        edittext1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
       String number=edittext1.getText().toString();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("mydata",MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit= sharedPreferences.edit();
                edit.putString("s1",number);
        edit.commit();

       // Intent intent = new Intent(this, phone_call.class);
       // intent.putExtra("s1",number);

    }
    private void phoneDialog(){

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.phone_call);

        dialog.setTitle("Call:");

        dialog.show();

    }

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           phoneDialog();

     }
 }
```

and following code in another class in which I have set Dialog.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Deepak on 7/5/2016.
 */
public class phone_call extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button2,button3;
    TextView editText;
    SharedPreferences shredpreference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.phone_call);
        button2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

        editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
       //String s1= intent.getStringExtra("s1");

shredpreference = getSharedPreferences("mydata",0);
      String s1=  shredpreference.getString("s1","null");
        editText.setText("Call"+ s1+":");

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
       // String s1= intent.getStringExtra("s1");
        shredpreference = getSharedPreferences("mydata",0);
        String s1=  shredpreference.getString("s1","null");

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button2:
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +s1 ));//change the number


                try{
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }

                catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                finishActivity(100);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put code for storing values at wrong place, so it will not take values anytime as it is in oncreate() methos,

**So remove below two lines from onCreate() method and write it in onCLick() method as below.**

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
          String number = edittext1.getText().toString();
          edit.putString("s1",number);
          edit.commit();

          phoneDialog();

     }
```